# Jira integration with Salesforce Articles

Tags: integration, knowledge, articles, richtextarea

I'm looking for help around Jira and Salesforce.  I currently have the Service Rocket plug-in working, cloud, with articles.  Below is the user story.

Questions:

1. Can the text formatting in Jira be preserved coming over to the SFDC rich text field?
2. Can Knowledge's Data Categories be set in the API?

**User Story**

As a CSR
I would like to see Jira Known Issues as SFDC Articles 
so that we don't have to search different areas of salesforce and just view all current how to articles with known issues and be in one place.

- When an issue of Project = Known Issue and Type = CSA incident is created in jira, the system should then create a corresponding Known Issue SFDC Article, as per the field mapping.
- When I view the article tab in Salesforce I can select one of the sub-tabs, data categories, across the top and choose a category to narrow my search
- When an issue is updated in Jira, then those updates need to appear in SFDC's article, pre the mapping.
- When a new attachment is added to an Issue in Jira, that attachment needs to be attached to the SFDC article.
- When an issue is closed in Jira, then the corresponding article in SFDC is deleted, so that no closed Known Issues are every seen by a VXA.

[image: Mapping]

Comment: Why not use a unified index and display both in a panel within Salesforce? (Jira and Kb Articles + any other data sources if any)

Comment: However you would  need to lookup for a managed package in the AppExchange to test.

Comment: Glls - interesting but how would the search work then if there is no data housed within salesforce knowledge?

Comment: through the unified index - the search queries an external service to fetch the data from confluence Jira

Comment: ah... as you can see I'm ignorant of this type of solution, how would I go about learning more around it?  (side topic is there a way I can be notified via email when comments come on those questions I ask?)

Comment: under your profile preferences you can enable email unread notifications

Comment: Yes I see the notification is there, however, it's set to send only every three hours, unable to make it sooner.
Back to topic at hand, the unified index... the customer wants one place for these CSR's to look so they have to appear as a Knowledge article.  In looking at Coveo's solution it appears to be a side panal.

Comment: Correct, it can be in the form of a side panel, which is usually a VF page in the console, you can get more information on the solution here https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SalesforceV2/Getting+Started+with+Coveo+for+Salesforce+Enterprise

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58284/discussion-between-glls-and-fifedog).